# с 404 на 301 Redirect

Tags: cms, opencart, redirect, http-status-code-301

Есть сайт на Opencart 2.3.0.2

Перепробовал кучу вариаций редиректа , ничего не работает.

Надо перенаправить со страницы:
`https://site.ru/sportivnoe-pitanie/aminokisloty-%7C-bcaa/`

На страницу:
`https://site.ru/sportivnoe-pitanie/aminokisloty`

Comment: А какие варианты пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /sportivnoe-pitanie/aminokisloty-%7C-bcaa/ http://www.site.ru/sportivnoe-pitanie/aminokisloty
```